# PySAL OLS Model: AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, regression, spatial, predict, pysal

I have divided my data into training and validation samples and have successfully fit my model with three types of linear models.  What I cannot figure out how to do is apply the model to the validation sample to evaluate the fit.  When I attempt to apply the model to the holdout sample (sorry, I know that this isn't a reproducible example but I think that the issue is pretty clear.  I'm just putting this snippet here for completeness.  Please be gentle!):

```
valid = validation.loc[:, x + [ "sale_amt"]] 
holdout1 = m1.predict(valid)
```

I get the following error message:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        8 
>        9 valid = validation.loc[:, x + [ "sale_amt"]]
>   ---> 10 holdout1 = m1.predict(valid)
>
> AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'predict'`

Other Python OLS regression packages have a 'predict' method, but it doesn't seem that PySAL does.  I realize that the function coefficients (betas) are available and will pursue applying them to my validation data directly, but I was hoping that there is a simple answer that I just missed.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if it is bad form to answer my own question, but I did come up with a solution.  I contacted Daniel Arribas-Bel, one of the PySAL developers, and he helped guide me to the result I was seeking.  Note that my PySAL OLS object is named m1, and my validation dataframe is called 'validation':

```
m1 = ps.model.spreg.OLS(...)
m1.intercept = m1.betas[0]  # Get the intercept from the betas array
m1.coefficients = m1.betas[1:len(m1.betas)] # Get the coefficients from the betas array
validation['predicted_price'] = m1.intercept + validation.loc[:, x].dot(  m1.coefficients)
```

Note that this is the method I would use for a non-spatial model adapted for the KNN model I built in PySAL and might not be technically fully correct for a spatial model.  *Caveat emptor.*

Comment: It's ok to self-answer your question, especially if it wasn't already having a working answer. You can even accept it, though you won't get the points :)